# Point of Borel Sets

Tags: measure-theory

One definition of a Borel set is as follows:

If $S$ is a topological space (where
it supports the concepts of open set): , then the Borel $\sigma-$ algebra on $S$ , denoted by $\mathbb{B}(S)$
, is the $\sigma-$ algebra generated by all the open sets.

I hope my question is not too broad- what is the advantage of working with a Borel Sigma algebra, as opposed to a generic sigma algebra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example: suppose that a $\sigma $-algebra contains a topology (this is the case of Borel). Then every real valued continuous function is measurable.